# DevExpress 15.1 WPF - Apply custom theme

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have trouble with applying custom theme to DevExpress 15.1 WPF application.

I have done steps:

- Create new Theme based on Metropolis Light with DevExpress Theme Editor(newest version)
- Compile it
- Add reference to compiled dll in my application
- Add this before `InitializeComponent()` in my MainWindow:

  `Theme theme = new Theme("MyTheme", "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyTheme.v15.1");
  theme.AssemblyName = "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyTheme.v15.1";
  Theme.RegisterTheme(theme);
  ThemeManager.SetTheme(this, theme);`

The result is exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

with inner exception

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.GetAssemblyFullName(Object key)
at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.RegisterThemeType(String themeName, String fullName, Object key)
```

Do you have idea what I'm doing wrong? Maybe it has changed in 15.1?

Comment: I believe you will get better luck if you ask on Devexpress forum

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close.

I added the following code to the OnStartup method of the App.xaml.cs:

```
var myTheme = new Theme("Dark", "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.Dark")
{
    AssemblyName = "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.Dark.v15.1"
};
Theme.RegisterTheme(myTheme);
ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = myTheme.Name;
```

Comment: In newer versions of DevExpress the ApplicationThemeName is deprecated. Use following line instead to set the default theme for the whole Application: `ApplicationThemeHelper.ApplicationThemeName = myTheme.Name;`